# Как парсить сложный массив в swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Прошу не ругайте, я знаю что в интернете полно примеров
Но они не подходят для меня, большинство из них из swift 3 
Пожалуйста дайте пример того как запарсить json(в котором массив, пример в фото) в table view?

```
{
"error": 0,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 14807,
        "title": "Привет мир",
        "link": "link.com",
        "delay_date": "2018-12-07 07:26:00",
        "image": "/uploads/5/image.jpg"
    },
```

}

Comment: Какие данные необходимо запарсить?

Comment: Ну допустим хочу вывести в tableview title и date

Answer (score 1):

Опишу метод которым сам пользуюсь, так как вариантов решения тьма.

С появлением swift 4, появился нативный парсер почитать можно тут [jsondecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder)

Так-же я использую не плохую обертку для этого класса [Unbox](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox).

У библиотеки объемное описание.  Но если не разберетесь, напишите. Я дам более детальный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался, держите кому нужно
Создаем модели:

```
struct News_data: Decodable {
let data: [Article_Data]

 enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
 case data = "data"
 }
}

struct Article_Data: Decodable {
 let title: String
  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
   case title = "title"
   }

  }
```

Объявляем массив :

```
var arrData = [Article_Data]()
```

Создаем функцию для JSON:

```
func getCoinData() {
 let jsonURL = "https://abctv.kz/ru/api/v1/getAllNews"
 guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
 guard let data = data else { return }
 do {
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
 let data_new = try decoder.decode(News_data.self, from: data)

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
 self.arrData = data_new.data
 self.tableview.reloadData()
 }

 } catch {
 print("Error is : \n\(error)")
 }
 }.resume()
 }
```

Вызываем функцию:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

getCoinData()
}
```

Возвращаем все в tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> 
Int {

return arrData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) 
as! MainTableViewCell
let dn = arrData[indexPath.row]
cell.textlabel.text = dn.title
```