# как декодировать JSON из переменной?

Tags: json, swift, swift4

У меня есть переменная, в которой находится массив JSON который я туда поместил
Как бы я мог декодировать его?

```
var dist: [String:Any] = [:]
```

...

```
let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
            self.dist = responseJSON as [String: Any]
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginSegue", sender: self.dist)
```

...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    if segue.identifier == "LoginSegue" {
        let tabVc = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navVc = tabVc.viewControllers!.first as! UINavigationController
        let chatVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! MainViewController
        chatVc.json = dist


    }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как парсить сложный массив в swift 4?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916825/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-swift-4)

Comment: Да нет, я имею в виду как вытащить json из переменной

Comment: а как вы его туда поместили ?

Comment: Ну смотрите, у меня есть форма авторизации. После успешной авторизации json записывается в переменную и отправляется на следующий контроллер. Так вот все хорошо передается. Как теперь извлечь эту переменную и потом уже как декодировать ее

Comment: Можно код увидеть, как вы записываете в переменную и как передаёте

Comment: Обновил вложение

Answer (score 0):

так вам не нужно его декодировать, у вас в переменной уже словарь лежит, просто по ключу получаете данные `json["my_key_string"]`, ну или создайте обект который в ините будет принимать `[String:Any]` и разбирать его по ключам будет что-то вроде `MyModel.init(jsonData: json)`